# Gas furnace ignites but then makes large knocking sound

Tags: repair, furnace

[image]

My gas furnace will ignite, but after the pilot goes on for a moment it creates a large periodic knocking sound over and over again instead of the fan starting. I have my suspicions, but I wanted to ask if anyone has run across this before.

Here is a link to the startup sequence
https://youtu.be/K2jNJ1Abh20

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like a relay bouncing to me, but let's see if one of our pros gives a more definitive answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The large buzz sounds like relay chatter to me also+ is your igniter always striking? I think that was the other noise I could hear a dirty eye could cause that but I don’t see one in the photo.+

Comment: It turned out to be the inducer motor. I replaced the complete inducer kit and we are working fine.